# React native vertical scrolling

Tags: react-native

I have  a basic screen where I have contents that go beyond the height of the screen. But the app is not scrolling vertically. I read the documentation of react native and came across 'ScrollView'. But do I have to then add a ScrollView for every screen that I add in the app.

Isn't vertical scrolling like a default thing?

I am a little new to react native so if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it isn't a default behaviour. If you want scroll you'll have to use `ScrollView` or `FlatList` depending what you need.

Comment: @OneQ. Thanks for the clarification. Will use those accordingly then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by @OneQ in the comments, `ScrollView` or `FlatList` will be needed according to how we need the contents to scroll. It is not a default behaviour that the app will scroll vertically.

This might be a very obvious thing but if anyone else is also looking for the same you can read the docs on [ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/using-a-scrollview) and [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/flatlist) for more clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a default behavior, but You don't need to add ScrollView to all your screens, add it only if your content exceeds screen height.
You Can also take a look to the React native documentation and read about ScrollView.